# What is the correct way to generate a json from file in GoogleAppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-io

I'm quite new to python and GAE, can anyone please provide some help/sample code for doing the following simple task? I managed to read a simple file and output it as a webpage but I need some slightly more complicated logic. Here is the pseudo code:

```
  open file;
  for each line in file {
    store first line as album title;
    for each song read {
      store first line as song title;
      store second line as song URL;
    }
  }
  Output the read in data as a json;
```

The file format will be something like this

*Album title1
 song1 title
 song1 url
 song2 title
 song2 url
 
 Album title2
 song1 title
 song1 url
 song2 title
 song2 url
 ..*

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  This will determine if you can use a built-in json library or not.

Comment: Have you looked at "from django.utils import simplejson"?

Comment: @Tryptich, since the OP very specifically said GoogleAppEngine more than once, what version of Python do you think they MIGHT be using except for 2.5? So, no built-in json, but of course as @Ethan says that doesn't matter since he can use the one from django. Also, print is not really how a GAE app normally does output, response.out.write is more likely to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Alex Yup - I don't have a ton of experience with GAE. Thanks for pointing that out.  Also I think I'll leave the print as a placeholder for "now do something with this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generator-based solution with a few nice features:

- Tolerates multiple blank lines between albums in text file
- Tolerates leading/trailing blank lines in text file
- Uses only an album's worth of memory at a time
- Demonstrates a lot of neato things you can do with Python :)

**albums.txt**

```
Album title1
song1 title
song1 url
song2 title
song2 url

Album title2
song1 title
song1 url
song2 title
song2 url
```

**Code**

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def gen_groups(lines):
   """ Returns contiguous groups of lines in a file """

   group = []

   for line in lines:
      line = line.strip()
      if not line and group:
         yield group
         group = []
      elif line:
         group.append(line)


def gen_albums(groups):
   """ Given groups of lines in an album file, returns albums  """

   for group in groups:
      title    = group.pop(0)
      songinfo = zip(*[iter(group)]*2)
      songs    = [dict(title=title,url=url) for title,url in songinfo]
      album    = dict(title=title, songs=songs)

      yield album


input = open('albums.txt')
groups = gen_groups(input)
albums = gen_albums(groups)

print simplejson.dumps(list(albums))
```

**Output**

```
[{"songs": [{"url": "song1 url", "title": "song1 title"}, {"url": "song2 url", "title": "song2 title"}], "title": "song2
title"},
{"songs": [{"url": "song1 url", "title": "song1 title"}, {"url": "song2 url", "title": "song2 title"}], "title": "song2
title"}]
```

Album information could then be accessed in Javascript like so:

```
var url = albums[1].songs[0].url;
```

Lastly, here's a note about that [tricky zip line](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: wow amazing upvoted, do I have to import anything for json.dumps to work in GAE?

Comment: Yeah just noted that GAE uses Python 2.5, which means you will have to import simplejson, which is nicely included with django, which is included with GAE :).  I changed my code accordingly - should work as is.

Comment: @erotsppa - a note about this solution: it DOES require that the input file is somewhat well-formed in that there are always complete song/url pairs.

Comment: I just tried your code, I got a NameError: global name 'gen_groups' is not defined. I put your two methods inside my class MainHandler. Is this correct?

Comment: @erotsppa - putting those two methods in the global scope will probably fix your problem, but you may want to research scope in Python in general.  You could also create a new module and dump those methods in there, then import the module as you would any other.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def albums(f):
  "" yields lists of strings which are the
     stripped lines for an album (blocks of
     nonblank lines separated by blocks of
     blank ones.
  """
  while True:
    # skip leading blank lines if any
    for line in f:
      if not line: return
      line = line.strip()
      if line: break
    result = [line]
    # read up to next blank line or EOF
    for line in f:
      if not line:
        yield result
        return
      line = line.strip()
      if not line: break
      result.append(line)
    yield result

def songs(album):
  """ yields lists of 2 lines, one list per song.
  """
  for i in xrange(1, len(album), 2):
    yield (album[i:i+2] + ['??'])[:2]

result = dict()
f = open('thefile.txt')
for albumlines in albums(f):
  current = result[albumlines[0]] = []
  for songlines in songs(albumlines):
    current.append( {
      'songtitle': songlines[0],
      'songurl': songlines[1]
    } )

response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(result))
```